# htaccess 301 obsolete query string to homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect (remove completely from URL) the old query string i used but which is now obsolete for my site.

So i need from

```
http://example.com/?_pu=true
```

to get users redirected to

```
http://example.com/
```

I need just 301 redirect to remove it from URL so users won't share that URL. Problem is the query string (?) i think cuz I have this code which doesnt work:

```
Redirect 301 /?_pu=true http://www.example.com
```

I also tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pu=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /? [L,R=301,NC]
```

But that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_pu= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:index.php|)$ /? [L,R=301,NC]
```