# How to remove GET parameters from URL on main page?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to make redirect if parameter start specified on main page. For example:

"site.com/?start=16" - must redirect to "site.com/"

"site.com/my-publishment?start=16" - must stay as is

I tried this code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)start=[^&]+(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

but it redirects me in both cases instead of only the first

Comment: This looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29225914/2943403

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to redirect from the root, you should use an empty match in your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)start=[^&]+(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

By using `(.*)` your are matching any path instead.

Comment: I can't check my changes because .htaccess doesn't apply my changes... Can you tell certain what I may to change?